# Detecting a repeating cycle in a sequence of numbers (python)

Tags: python, numbers, sequence, cycle

I was wondering what would be a a fairly 'common' or normal way of doing this. Wasn't really looking for the shortest possible answer like a 2-liner or anything. I've just quickly put this piece of code together but I can't not feel like there's way too much in there.
Also if there are any libraries that could help with this, that would be very nice.

```
def get_cycle(line):
    nums = line.strip().split(' ')

    # 2 main loops, for x and y
    for x in range(2, len(nums)): # (starts at 2, assuming the sequence requires at least 2 members)
        for y in range(0, x):
            # if x is already in numbers before it
            if nums[x] == nums[y]:
                seq = [nums[x]] # (re)start the sequence
                adder = 1       # (re)set the adder to 1
                ok = True       # (re)set ok to be True
                # while the sequence still matches (is ok) and
                # tail of y hasn't reached start of x
                while ok and y + adder < x:
                    if nums[x + adder] == nums[y + adder]:  # if next y and x match
                        seq.append(nums[x + adder])         # add the number to sequence
                        adder += 1                          # increase adder
                    else:
                        ok = False                          # else the sequence is broken
                # if the sequence wasn't broken and has at least 2 members
                if ok and len(seq) > 1:
                    print(' '.join(seq))    # print it out, separated by an empty space
                    return
```

Comment: Please try to describe in words what all of this is supposed to do. It's pretty dense.

Comment: If this is working properly, it may be a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: sorry for the density. 
It reads a sequence of numbers eg. '3 0 5 5 1 5 1 6 8'
and has to find the first sequence of numbers that repeat , in this case the '5 1 5 1', and print out that single sequence ('5 1').
EDIT: also yeah, this works, but I guess there has to be a better way

----input text file:
2 0 6 3 1 6 3 1 6 3 1
---- output
6 3 1------

Comment: why does it not print ('5')? should it print the _longest_ sequence? only sequences of length > 2?

Comment: yeah - # if the sequence wasn't broken and has at least 2 members
            ----if ok and len(seq) > 1:----
has to be atleast 2 members... I guess 1 number isnt really a sequence

Comment: @falconvk - Thanks for the clarification, I edited my answer so it should now do what you want.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I may not be properly understanding this, but I think there is a very simple solution with regex.

```
(.+ .+)( \1)+
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'(.+ .+)( \1)+')
>>> match = regex.search('3 0 5 5 1 5 1 6 8')
>>> match.group(0)    # entire match
'5 1 5 1'
>>> match.group(1)    # repeating portion
'5 1'
>>> match.start()     # start index of repeating portion
6

>>> match = regex.search('2 0 6 3 1 6 3 1 6 3 1')
>>> match.group(1)
'6 3 1'
```

Here is how it works, `(.+ .+)` will match at least two numbers (as many as possible) and place the result into capture group 1.  `( \1)+` will match a space followed by the contents of capture group 1, at least once.

And an extended explanation for the string `'3 0 5 5 1 5 1 6 8'`:

- `(.+ .+)` will originally match the entire string, but will give up characters off the end because `( \1)+` will fail, this backtracking will occur until `(.+ .+)` cannot match at the beginning of the string at which point the regex engine will move forward in the string and try again
- This will happen until the capture group starts at the second 5, it will give up characters at the end until `'5 1'` is captured, at which point the regex is looking for any number of `' 5 1'` for `( \1)+`, it will of course find this and the match will succeed

Comment: It doesn't have to be the longest sequence. It just has to be a repeating cycle, meaning something like 1 3 6 5 1 3 6, doesn't have one, because theres a 5 in between.
Needs to find the 1st one happening, not the longest one

Comment: really looking forward to seeing the explanation.
I've been doing python for about a week now, and am really new to the whole regex thing. Guess I should start looking much more at it.

Comment: Thanks. Now I just need to really look into it and see what each part of it does and why. Never even used the compile() so.. Much appreciated!

Comment: `(.+ .+)` I thought this will always find exactly 2 groups of 1 or more characters, groups being separated by a single space char. and then the `( \1)+` part will match any number of those 2-piece groups following it, which is why I'm still confused about how that matches `6 3 1 6 3 1`

Answer (score 3):

Your question is really "do all items from x:x+k match items from y:y+k".  That is, does a k-length subset occur twice in the line?

And you want x:x+k non-overlapping with y:y+k.  The easy way to do this is to define y as x plus some offset, d.  If you assure that k <= d < len(line)-x-k, then you're always looking within the boundaries of the line.

You'll then vary k from 1 to len(line)//2, looking for various length duplicates at a given offset from each other.

The offset from x to y, d, will vary between 1 and len(line)-x-k.

The starting position for x, similarly will vary from 0 to len(line)//2.

So, the "all" part is something like this: `all( line[i] == line[i+d] for i in range(x,x+k) )` for various legal values of `d`, `x` and `k`.

Comment: +1 for transforming a loosely posed question into an actionable problem spec.

Comment: I can't really tell from just looking at the line you wrote, but the sequence has to repeat right after 'itself', not just occur twice wherever in the line. I'll give it a try though, thanks.

Comment: If the offset, d, between x and y is == k, then you're looking for a k-length sequences right next to each other.